# Alternate to use of repeater in cognos report studio

Tags: repeater, cognos-8

I am creating a report using Cognos 8.4 Report Studio which contains several lists. I need to use a repeater so that the data can be displayed for multiple members rather than a single member. I have been advised that use of repeater in a large report will affect performance. So is there a alternate way to using repeaters in cognos report studio and yet achieve the same result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think there are any better alternative for repeaters. The performance depends on the server and how well it is configured to handle multiple requests.

Answer (score 0):

If you unlock the report layout you can use a list to do layout operations like you can with a repeater (if you aren't spanning the repeater cells horizontally).

Please refer to IBM Cognos Infocenter for more details on report objects. 
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/c8bi/v8r4m0/index.jsp